# Multiple Mysql Cross Reference Tables, or One (by adding an extra field storing reference type)

Tags: mysql, optimization

prx_tags_sportsitems and prx_tags_fishingitems are cross reference tables that link the sportsitem / fishing item (OwnerID) to the Tag (TagID).

**Is it better to have separate cross reference tables for each type of item, or to combine them?** In my REAL database, I have 10+ types of items, which is why I am considering joining them, however I'm wondering if the speed of queries would be affected.

So it's either:

> CREATE TABLE prx_tags_sportsitems (
>   TagID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   OwnerID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (TagID,OwnerID));
>
> **AND**
>
> CREATE TABLE prx_tags_fishingitems (
>   TagID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   OwnerID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (TagID,OwnerID));
>
> **Using Query:**
>
> SELECT prx_sportsitems.* FROM
>   prx_sportsitems, prx_tags_sportsitems
>   WHERE prx_tags_sportsitems.OwnerID =
>   prx_sportsitems.ID  AND
>   prx_tags_sportsitems.TagID = (SELECT
>   ID FROM prx_tags WHERE TagName =
>   'aerobic') ORDER BY
>   prx_sportsitems.DateAdded DESC LIMIT
>   0,30;
>
> **...and same query again for prx_tags_fishingitems**

**OR,** Is it better to join these tables into one by using "OwnerType" to distinguise between sportsitems and fishingitems? Like so:

> CREATE TABLE prx_tags_items (
>   TagID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   OwnerID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   OwnerType varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (TagID,OwnerID));
>
> **Using Query:**
>
> SELECT prx_sportsitems.* FROM
>   prx_sportsitems, prx_tags_items
>   WHERE prx_tags_items.OwnerID =
>   prx_sportsitems.ID  AND
>   prx_tags_items.TagID = (SELECT
>   ID FROM prx_tags WHERE TagName =
>   'aerobic') AND 
>   prx_tags_items.OwnerType = '**sportsitems**' ORDER BY 
>   prx_sportsitems.DateAdded DESC LIMIT
>   0,30;
>
> **...and same query again for prx_fishingitems, setting OwnerType to "fishingitems"**

I like the idea of joining the tables using OwnerType, since I can then easily create a new OwnerType without creating a new cross reference table for each OwnerType, but my concern is that it will slow down the mysql queries significantly when adding in the line:

> AND prx_tags_items.OwnerType = '**[owner item type here]**'

I appreciate any help and advice. I want to get started soon :)

**UPDATE:** Would adding an index (primary key) for "OwnerType" help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the cross-reference table may be a matter of preference in this situation, but as your data sets grow it may become cumbersome for both yourself and for your growing needs of the application to continue to keep that up.

Rather, I would rewrite the queries above to eliminate subqueries and implied joins. I would also add an index on anything that gets evaluated.

A first-blush rewrite would look like this:

```
select * from prx_sportsitems psi
left join prx_tags_items pti on (pti.ownerid=psi.id)
left join prx_tags pt on (pti.tagid=pt.id)
where pt.tagname = 'aerobic'
and pti.ownertype='sportsitems'
order by psi.dateadded desc
limit 0,30
```

And will *require* indexes on the following columns:

- prx_sportsitems.id
- prx_tags_items.id
- prx_tags.id
- prx_tags.tagname
- prx_tags_items.ownertype

Also, don't sort unless you *absolutely* have to!

Best of luck!

Comment: Great! I'll consolidate it to one table then and utilize "OwnerType". BTW: I assume when you say prx_tags_items.ID needs indexes, you mean prx_tags_items.TagID? There is no prx_tags_items.ID in the above query you wrote?

Comment: UPDATE: I just got some data into a new structure as designed above. I ran my original query and yours using left joins. They are running at virtually the same speed on my localhost mysql query browser. In fact, my original query (subquery) runs slightly faster. Hmm... curious.

Comment: I was never sure what the bracketed mysql query browser speed meant. However, upon looking again I realize that the left join query is actually faster in both, so I suppose the left join is better!

Comment: Ah, fantastic. Thanks for clarifying. I would also like to stress the importance of the indexes... you really need the indexes for maximum performance.

Comment: Thanks. Indexes have been added and I'm getting query speeds of about 0.03 seconds. However, in brackets it says 0.0019 seconds so I'm not sure which to go by. I'm making the assumption that mysql query browser shows a indexed speed or something else in the brackets.

Comment: Update: I found out what the two values mean. The first is the amount of time it took mysql to send however many rows it is, the second however many seconds it took to run the query. If looking for performance, better to look at the one in brackets then!